# How can i add my notification details to a recycler that is found in another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an activity that holds five fragments, One of the fragments is a notification fragment which has a recycler view and adds items to it , now i have another fragment that has an api request and creates a notification which returns data as a notification , i cant find a way to get the data from the notification and add it to the recycler view found in the notification fragment.

**here is my notification code found on the fragment thats has to add the data on the recycler view found on the notification fragment**

```
 //create an intent to open notification intent
                                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity (), NotificationFragmentCict.class);
                                    NotificationFragmentCict fragment = new NotificationFragmentCict ();
                                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                    //Replace intent with Bundle and put it in the transaction
                                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_cict, fragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_cict,fragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.commit();


                                    intent.setAction (Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                    long when = System.currentTimeMillis ();
                                    intent.addCategory (Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                                    intent.putExtra ("controlnumber","Controlnumber:" + " " + studentClearance.getControlNumber () );
                                    intent.putExtra ("reason","Reason: Full Transcript Fee");
                                    intent.putExtra ("time"," " +when);
                                    intent.putExtra ("department","From : SUA Bursar");
                                    intent.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);


                                    PendingIntent statusPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity (getActivity (),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                    NotificationFragmentCict notificationFragmentCict =new NotificationFragmentCict ();
                                    notificationFragmentCict.fillNotification (R.drawable.bursar, "Bursar", ""+studentClearance.getControlNumber (),"min");

                                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (getActivity (), CHANNEL_IDcontrolnumber_Fulltranscript);
                                    builder.setSmallIcon (R.drawable.ic_near_me_black_24dp);
                                    builder.setContentTitle ("Control Number For Full Transcript");
                                    builder.setPriority (NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
                                    builder.setAutoCancel (true);
                                    builder.setContentIntent (statusPendingIntent);
```

**Here is my notification fragment which has a function that adds the new item to the recycler view**

```
 public void fillNotification(int mImage, String mtext, String mtext2, String mDate)
    {
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (getContext ());
        mAdapter = new NotificationAdapter (notimodels);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        notimodels.add (0,new NotificationModel (mImage,mtext,mtext2,mDate));


        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
```

When i use that fill Notification to other fragments it throws and error that

```
Process: com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp, PID: 23358
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.Fragments.NotificationFragmentCict.fillNotification(NotificationFragmentCict.java:87)
        at com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.Fragments.AccountFragmentCict$4$1$1.onDataChange(AccountFragmentCict.java:401)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a tricky process!

1. Create an `Intent` for your activity which contains the fragment
2. Attach your data with your activity intent by calling `intent.putExtra(...)`
3. Then create a `Pending Intent` and attach your activity intent with it
4. Now attach the pending intent with your `Notification`
5. Call `notificationManager.notify(...)`
6. Now, when a user taps on the notification, the activity intent will be started.
7. In your activity, you should get the intent data by using `intent.getIntExtra(....)` or `intent.getStringExtra(....)` etc.
8. After collecting your intent data from your activity, now you can call your fragment and pass the data on your fragment to update your `RecylerView`

Comment: So you mean i just pass data between two fragments right, but how can i trigger the function that it should add the data now

Comment: have done so but still gets the same error when i call the fill notification method check out have updated my code, i cant add a new item on the recycler from outside the class that contains the recycler view

Comment: Call `notificationFragmentCict.fillNotification(...)` this from your activity. Not from the notification. Because activity can only create it's fragment. Get the data in your activity. Then, instantiate your fragment from your activity and pass the data to your fragment!

Comment: i have called the message outside the notification but it throws the same error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.Fragments.NotificationFragmentCict.fillNotification(NotificationFragmentCict.java:87)
        at com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.Fragments.AccountFragmentCict.onCreateView(AccountFragmentCict.java:105)

Comment: This error is showing because your fragment's view is not created yet. That's why recyclerview is null and you're invoking `setHasFixedSize(...)` method on you null recyclerview.

Comment: yes its true how can i solve that brother thats my concern passing data is okay i can do that